# Unable to Fetch User Orders - Getting 401 (Unauthorized) Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, express, react-hooks

I am currently working on a React application where users can view their orders. I have implemented user authentication using JSON Web Tokens (JWT). However, when attempting to fetch the user's orders, I am consistently getting a 401 (Unauthorized) error.

React components

```
// UserOrders.jsx

import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { format } from 'date-fns';
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';

function UserOrders() {
  const [order, setOrder] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchOrder = async () => {
      try {
        const token = Cookies.get('token');
        if (!token) {
          console.error('No token found');
          return;
        }

        const response = await fetch('http://localhost:4000/api/v1/orders/me', {
          method: 'GET',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
          },
        });

        if (response.ok) {
          const data = await response.json();
          console.log(data.order);
          setOrder(data.order);
        } else {
          console.error('Failed to fetch user orders');
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching user orders', error);
      }
    };

    fetchOrder();
  }, []);

  // ... rest of the component
}

export default UserOrders;
```

server side

```
// server.js

const orderRouter = require('express').Router();
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

orderRouter.get("/me", isAuthenticated, async (req, res) => {
  const token = req.cookies.token;

  try {
    if (!token) {
      return res.status(401).send("Unauthorized: No token found");
    }

    const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, 'your-secret-key');
    const userId = decodedToken.userId;

    const order = await Orders.find({ user: userId });
    res.json({ order });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(401).send("Unauthorized: Invalid token");
  }
});
```

1.Check Token Existence
2.I've ensured that the token is being sent correctly in the Authorization header
3.On the server side, I'm decoding and verifying the token.

Comment: `const token = req.cookies.token;` - your request appears to be cross-origin - in which case you currently won't be sending (or accepting) any cookies, because the `credentials` option is not appropriately set.

Comment: _Why_ would you want to fetch the token out of a cookie on the receiving end to begin with here - when you already sent it via the `Authorization` header?

Comment: but before when i tried sent it with cookie and receiving form cookies it does not worked that's why I tried chatgpt for it

Comment: Why your current code would not _sent_ any cookie value with this cross-origin request, was already mentioned. You need to set the `credentials` option of the `fetch` request to the appropriate value.

Comment: ok ok thanks by adding app.use(cors({
  origin: 'http://localhost:5173',
  credentials: true,
}));    this to serverside code now it is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're sending the token as an Authorization header:

```
headers: {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
}
```

But looking for it in the cookies:

```
const token = req.cookies.token;
```

Get it from the headers instead:

```
const token = req.headers.authorization;
```

(You may need to filter out the `"Bearer "` part of the value before validating the token, your debugging can confirm.)

Comment: but what if i want to get it from cookies

Comment: @DhruvGoswami: Is it *in* the cookies?  What have you done to confirm this or add it to the cookies?  If you want the value to be in a cookie, why do you put it in a header?

Comment: ok ok thanks by adding app.use(cors({
  origin: 'http://localhost:5173',
  credentials: true,
}));    this to serverside code now it is working   thank u david